# How to center image using NSLayoutConstraints.constraintsWithVisualFormat next to Labels using swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to get my uitableviewcell to display a message, username, and user image.  The Cell is set to auto adjust height with size of message and name.  I would like the user image or avatar to center to the left of the 2 labels.  I haven't got it to work without the image distorting.  Here is my code....

```
let views = ["nameLabel": nameLabel, "bodyLabel": bodyLabel, "avatar":avatar]

        //Horizontal constraints
        let bodyLabelHorizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-5-[avatar(30)]-5-[bodyLabel]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

        let nameLabelHorizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-5-[avatar(30)]-5-[nameLabel]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

        self.addConstraints(bodyLabelHorizontalConstraints)
        self.addConstraints(nameLabelHorizontalConstraints)

        //Vertical constraints
        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[bodyLabel]-5-[nameLabel]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        let avatarVerticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[avatar(30)]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)

        self.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
        self.addConstraints(avatarVerticalConstraints)
```

Comment: So your constraints are putting it where you want, but the image is distorted? If that's the case, try setting `avatar.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit`.

Comment: @ConnorNeville I need the height to equal the first vertical restraint; which is "V:|-10-[bodyLabel]-5-[nameLabel]-10-|"